# If $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $kA$ contains an open ball, does $A$ also contains an open ball? $A$ is any subset of a Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$kA = \{ka | a \in A\} = \{x | x = ka, a \in A\}$.

Intuitively, this is certainly true. I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously.

My thought process so far has been that if $B(y', r) \subset kA$, then $y' = ka$ for some $a \in A$. Then $(1/k) y = a \in A$. Then I'm not sure what to do next. It is known that $A$ is closed, maybe this is to help somehow, but I'm stuck and not making any progress.

To give full details, I'm trying to understand the open mapping theorem, and not understanding the assertion on the third last line **"$T(B_1)$ also contains an open ball..."**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a direct consequence of the absolute homogeneity of the norm: Let $X$ be a normed space. For every scalar $\lambda$ the scalar multiplication with $\lambda$
$$
 f_\lambda \colon X \to X, \quad x \mapsto \lambda x
$$
has
$$
 \| f_\lambda(x) - f_\lambda(y) \|
 = \| \lambda x - \lambda y \|
 = |\lambda| \| x-y \|
 \quad\text{for all $x,y \in X$}.
$$
So for $\lambda \neq 0$ and every $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ it follows that $f_\lambda$ maps the open ball $B_r(x)$ bijectively into the open ball $B_{|\lambda| r}(\lambda x)$.

So if $kA$ contains an open ball $B_r(x)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $B_r(x) \subseteq kA$, then we must have $k > 0$ (because otherwise $kA = \{0\}$, which has empty interior), and thus
$$
 B_{r/k}(x/k) = f_{1/k}(B_r(x)) \subseteq f_{1/k}(kA) = A.
$$
So $A$ also contains an open ball.

Comment: Your answer much appreciated, I was wondering if you'd comment on the following approach:

If $y \in kA$, then $y = kz$ for $z \in A$. $(1/k)y = z$.

If $B_r(y_0) \subset kA$, then $\| y- y_0\| < r$ $\implies \|kz - y_0\| < r \implies \|z - (1/k)y_0\| < r/k.$ Then $z \in B_{r/k}((1/k)y_0).$ But then is this ball contained in $A$? How? (I don't want to use the map, but would like to show this 'directly' instead)

Comment: Notice that these implications are already equivalences, i.e. if $y,z \in X$ with $y = kz$, then $z \in B_{r/k}((1/k)y_0) \iff y \in B_r(y_0)$. (This is also just the my statement that $f_{1/k}$ maps $B_r(y_0)$ bijectively onto $B_{r/k}((1/k)y_0)$.) That $B_{r/k}((1/k)y_0) \subseteq A$ follows from this, because $z \in B_{r/k}((1/k)y_0) \iff kz \in B_r(y_0) \implies kz \in kA \iff z \in A$. For the implication in the middle we use that $B_r(y_0) \subseteq kA$.

Comment: Thank you so so much for all your help.